# Update statement to keep tracking of SortOrder in database

Tags: c#, sql, sorting

I have a list of product images on screen. When the user drags and drops an image to resort I have access to the oldIndex and the newIndex.

**Lets say I have the following:**
Product1[index: 0]
Product2[index: 1]
Product3[index: 2]
Product4[index: 3]
Product5[index: 4]
Product6[index: 5]

And the user decides to put Product2 before Product4

I am trying to figure out what my db update statement would be. I was reading another post and saw that someone said you should update the SortOrder field of all Products that are >= the newIndex and then afterwards update the new product to be in the newIndex.

Something about this seems off to me, this would leave me with the following:
Product1[index: 0]
Product2[index: 2]
Product3[index: 3]
Product4[index: 4]
Product5[index: 5]
Product6[index: 6]

I am really trying to achieve this where my indexes stay in perfect sequence with no gaps. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've done this kind of thing using Entity Framework before. Does it need to be in SQL?

Comment: @BlakeRivell, Please specify which SQL server do you use?

Comment: @dans yes I am using entity framework I was just assuming it would be easiest for someone to describe to me in SQL terms. I am using the kendo UI sorting widget that allows me to drag and drop images in a list view and onChange get access to the oldIndex and newIndex of the moved item. My plan was to make an ajax call at this point to update all records sort orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I wrote a void to handle the grunt-work. Since I needed to do this with multiple types of entities, all of which had a `SortOrder` column, I created an interface called `ISortable` that contained a `SortOrder` column. If you're just doing this with one db table you can substitute any instances of `ISortable` with whatever your entity is named.

What needs to happen outside of this void is:

Get your item from the db and store its old sort order in a variable (`oldSortOrder`), then set the new sort order (`newSortOrder`) of your item, then set a variable to be all other items that aren't the one you just updated (`list`). This also accounts for items being removed from the db, just set `newSortOrder` to `0` in your ajax call.

**WebApi method:**

```
// Code is activated when accessed via http PUT
public void PutItem(int itemId, int newSortOrder)
{
    // using makes sure Context is disposed of properly
    using (var Context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var oldSortOrder = 0;

        IEnumerable<ISortable> itemsToReorder = null;

        // Get moved item from database
        var item = Context.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == itemId);

        // Before we set the new sort order, set a variable to the
        // old one. This will be used to reorder the other items.
        oldSortOrder = item.SortOrder;

        // Get all items except the one we grabbed above.
        itemsToReorder = Context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemId != itemId);

        // Delete if the item is set for deletion (newSortOrder = 0)
        if (newSortOrder == 0)
        {
            Context.Items.Remove(item);
        }
        // Otherwise, set the new sort order.
        else
        {
            item.SortOrder = newSortOrder;
        }

        // Pass other items into reordering logic.
        ReOrder(itemsToReorder, oldSortOrder, newSortOrder);

        // Save all those changes back to the database
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Reordering void:**

```
public static void ReOrder(IEnumerable<ISortable> list, 
    int oldSortOrder, 
    int newSortOrder)
{
    IEnumerable<ISortable> itemsToReorder;

    // Pare down the items to just those that will be effected by the move.
    // New sort order of 0 means the item has been deleted.
    if (newSortOrder == 0)
    {
        itemsToReorder = list.Where(x => x.SortOrder > oldSortOrder);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is just a long inline if statement. Applies Where()
        // conditions depending on the old and new sort variables.
        itemsToReorder = list.Where(x => (oldSortOrder < newSortOrder
            ? x.SortOrder <= newSortOrder &&
            x.SortOrder > oldSortOrder
            : x.SortOrder >= newSortOrder &&
            x.SortOrder < oldSortOrder));
    }

    foreach (var i in itemsToReorder)
    {
        // Original item was moved down
        if (newSortOrder != 0 && oldSortOrder < newSortOrder)
        {
            i.SortOrder -= 1;
        }
        // Original item was moved up
        else if (newSortOrder != 0 && oldSortOrder > newSortOrder)
        {
            i.SortOrder += 1;
        } // Original item was removed.
        else
        {
            i.SortOrder -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need some clarification. I'm almost certain I didn't explain everything adequately.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. So I guess my Web API method only needs two params. The id of the entity that is being moved and additionally the new sortIndex of it. What happens when I go to delete a record do I run the same logic afterwards?

Comment: D'oh. I didn't include the deletion part. I'll update. You basically send `itemId` and `newSortOrder  = 0`.

Comment: I implemented this logic exactly and for some reason I keep getting duplicates during reorder. For example two of them will have SortOrder of 6. Is your sort ordering zero based? I am making mine zero based because the kendo ui control I am using sees the first one as index 0. Additionally I believe I am going to have to use sortOrder -1 for my deletion since 0 is technically the first item right?

Comment: Yeah, it's 1 based. You'll have to make some adjustments to get it to work with 0 based.

Comment: I ended up getting this all sorted out. For delete I simply was able to lookup all of the items where the SortOrder is greater than the one being deleted and just subtracted their SortOrder by 1. Do you have any advice on initial save how I can make sure the first batch of items added has a proper sort order from 1-5 for example. My problem is that the async upload technique I am using makes a request for each of the 5 files individually so I am unable to set the initial sort orders during the initial save.

Comment: Maybe send an additional field/value for the order along with the file in the async upload. Then it wouldn't matter what order they're processed in.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Product') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Product

CREATE TABLE #Product(
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,SortOrder INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Product (Name, SortOrder)
VALUES 
 ('Product1', 0)
,('Product2', 1)
,('Product3', 2)
,('Product4', 3)
,('Product5', 4)
,('Product6', 5)

DECLARE 
    @NewIndex INT
    ,@OldIndex INT

SET @OldIndex = 4   --'Product5'
SET @NewIndex = 2   -- After 'Product2'

IF @NewIndex < @OldIndex    -- Move UP
    UPDATE #Product
        SET SortOrder = CASE 
                        WHEN SortOrder = @OldIndex THEN @NewIndex 
                        ELSE SortOrder + 1
                        END
    WHERE SortOrder BETWEEN @NewIndex AND @OldIndex;
ELSE                        -- Move DOwn
    UPDATE #Product
        SET SortOrder = CASE 
                        WHEN SortOrder = @OldIndex THEN @NewIndex 
                        ELSE SortOrder - 1
                        END
    WHERE SortOrder BETWEEN @OldIndex AND @NewIndex;

SELECT * FROM #Product ORDER BY SortOrder
```